# MySQL exception "connection lost during query", "MySQL server has gone away" and "command out of sync"

Tags: c++, mysql, multithreading

I have a code with c++, which use SQLAPI++ library. In my code I've tried to open connection for mysql, then create two commands, which works with same connection, and call that command from two threads. 
During execution of my code I've received exception "Connection lost during query" and "MySQL server has gone away".
Sometime I receive exception "Command out of sync, you can't run this command now".
I've tried to increase wait_timeout տօ 150 and max_allowed_package տօ 64M, but my problem is not solved.
Bellow you can find c++ code.

```
int main()
{

  try
  {
    SAConnection saConnection;
    saConnection.Connect("scada", "root", "123qwerty!@#", SA_MySQL_Client);
    saConnection.setAutoCommit(SA_AutoCommitOff);   

    SACommand saCommand1{&saConnection, "select * from Node"};
    SACommand saCommand2{&saConnection, "select * from Node limit 1"};

    // VM: TODO: saCommand1.setOption("UseStatement") = "TRUE";
    // VM: TODO: saCommand2.setOption("UseStatement") = "TRUE";
    saCommand1.setOption("HandleResult") = "store";
    saCommand2.setOption("HandleResult") = "store";

    auto f1 = std::async(std::launch::async, [&]{ saCommand1.Execute(); saConnection.Commit(); });
    auto f2 = std::async(std::launch::async, [&]{ saCommand2.Execute(); saConnection.Commit(); });
    f1.get();
    f2.get();

    //saConnection.Commit(); // BOOM!

/*
    while (saCommand1.FetchNext())
      std::cerr << "======== fetching a record from saCommand1" << std::endl;
    while (saCommand2.FetchNext())
      std::cerr << "======== fetching a record from saCommand2" << std::endl;
*/
  }
  catch(const SAException& ex)
  {
    std::cerr << "==== ex.what() is " << static_cast<const char*>(ex.ErrText()) << std::endl;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using one connection from two `std::async` objects, probably from two threads, which is not supported. Create two connections to the database, one for each `std::async`.